# how to fix the issue in pseudo code algorithms with multiple precedures in latex?

Tags: formatting, algorithms, pseudocode

I am formetting pseudo code algorithms with multiple procedures in it, but formatting has somes issues such as `endProcedure=0`in latex output though. How can I fix this? thanks

**my current script**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\algnewcommand{\LineComment}[1]{\State \(\triangleright\) #1}

\algdef{SE}[PROCEDURE]{Procedure}{EndProcedure}%
   [2]{\algorithmicprocedure\ \textproc{#1}\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{(#2)}}%
   {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicprocedure}%
\algdef{SE}[FUNCTION]{Function}{EndFunction}%
   [2]{\algorithmicfunction\ \textproc{#1}\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{(#2)}}%
   {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfunction}%

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{some text for caption}
\label{alg:mergesort}

\LineComment{ s,a: text, text, or text}
\LineComment{ $text: text, or text}
\LineComment{ text, text, or text}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{sort}{s,a}
\State $\mathbf{z_a} \gets \text{srt}_s(a)$
\State $\mathbf{z_a} \gets \text{srt}_a(a)$
\State \Return $\mathbf{z_a}, \mathbf{z_a}$
\EndProcedure
\Procedure{mergesort}{s,a,t}
\State $\mathbf{z_t} \gets \text{srt}_t(t)$
\State $\mathbf{z_a, z_a} \gets \text{sort}(s,a)$
\State $\mathbf{z_a} \gets \mathbf{z_a}+\mathbf{z_t}$ \Comment{text, text, or text}
\State $\mathbf{z_a} \gets \mathbf{z_a}+\mathbf{z_t}$
\State $\mathbf{z_{\hat{a}}} \gets \text{mergesort}([\mathbf{z_a}, \mathbf{z_a}])$
\State $\mathbf{\hat{a}} \gets \text{pred}_a(\mathbf{z_{\hat{a}}})$
\State \Return $\mathbf{\hat{a}}$
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put these `\LineComment` in the `algorithmic` enviroment.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\algnewcommand{\LineComment}[1]{\State \(\triangleright\) #1}

\algdef{SE}[PROCEDURE]{Procedure}{EndProcedure}%
   [2]{\algorithmicprocedure\ \textproc{#1}\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{(#2)}}%
   {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicprocedure}%
\algdef{SE}[FUNCTION]{Function}{EndFunction}%
   [2]{\algorithmicfunction\ \textproc{#1}\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{(#2)}}%
   {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfunction}%

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{some text for caption}
\label{alg:mergesort}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\LineComment{ s,a: text, text, or text}
\LineComment{ $text: text, or text$}
\LineComment{ text, text, or text}
\Procedure{sort}{s,a}
\State $\mathbf{z_a} \gets \text{srt}_s(a)$
\State $\mathbf{z_a} \gets \text{srt}_a(a)$
\State \Return $\mathbf{z_a}, \mathbf{z_a}$
\EndProcedure
\Procedure{mergesort}{s,a,t}
\State $\mathbf{z_t} \gets \text{srt}_t(t)$
\State $\mathbf{z_a, z_a} \gets \text{sort}(s,a)$
\State $\mathbf{z_a} \gets \mathbf{z_a}+\mathbf{z_t}$ \Comment{text, text, or text}
\State $\mathbf{z_a} \gets \mathbf{z_a}+\mathbf{z_t}$
\State $\mathbf{z_{\hat{a}}} \gets \text{mergesort}([\mathbf{z_a}, \mathbf{z_a}])$
\State $\mathbf{\hat{a}} \gets \text{pred}_a(\mathbf{z_{\hat{a}}})$
\State \Return $\mathbf{\hat{a}}$
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I suggest to use `algpseudocodex`, it is more powerful, such as `\LComment`.

Comment: how can I add empty line one procedure to another like new procedure should be line 10, and line 9 should be empty; how can I do this? how can I put linecomment with some indent outside of algorithmic ? can you suggest some ideas on this? thanks

Comment: @kim You can just add `\State` before `\Procedure{mergesort}{s,a,t}`.

Comment: @kim You can use `\Statex` to write some line without line number, I think this is what you want.

Comment: can we put linecomment  with certain indentation outside algorithmic ?I saw some people did in the paper, so trying to figure out what latex code they used; I mean how to make multiple linecomment like itemize format.  any thoughts?

Comment: @kim Can you give some image? I can help you code it.

Comment: thanks, updated my post with pseudo code image that I want to reproduce. thanks

Comment: @kim `\algnewcommand{\LineComment}[1]{\Statex \(\triangleright\) #1}`.